# Ubuntu wont shows wifi

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I have installed ubuntu 16.

What i have problem is, is that it wont shot wifi pannel / wifi connections.

i have tried to unblock it using

```
sudo rfkill list all
```

output is

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

when i go to driver manager and select additional software i see that it should have installed driver
[image]

How can i make it right? Additional photo of my panel
Thanks for help.
[image]

Comment: Please start here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180